# Intersection of two planes $a \cdot x = 0 $ and $b \cdot x = 0$ with $(a, b)$ dependent and indpendent.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I'm trying to solve the following question:

Let $U=\left\{\left(x_1, x_2, x_3\right) \in \mathbb{R}^3: a_1 x_1+a_2 x_2+a_3 x_3=0\right\}$ and $V=\left\{\left(x_1, x_2, x_3\right) \in \mathbb{R}^3: b_1 x_1+b_2 x_2+b_3 x_3=0\right\}$, where $a=\left(a_1, a_2, a_3\right)$ and $b=\left(b_1, b_2, b_3\right)$ are vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$.
Express the intersection $U \cap V$ as the span of a list of vectors,

a) under the assumption that $(a, b)$ is linearly independent;
b) under the assumption that $(a, b)$ is linearly dependent.

I don't know what independent v. dependent tells us about the resulting planes. I realize that if the planes intersect the dimension of the subspace will be 1 and if not, it'll just be the zero vector. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: $(a)$ the 2 planes must be non-parallel and hence intersect in a line. $(b)$ the 2 planes are parallel through $0$ and hence the same

Answer (score 2):

Both planes pass through the origin.  If $a$ and $b$ are dependent then this means that

$ b = k \ a $

And it would follow that $U = V$, i.e. the two planes are actually the same plane.  So their intersection is the plane $U$ (which is also the plane $V$).

If $a$ and $b$ are independent, then the intersection will be the line

$ \ell(t) = t (a \times b) $

i.e., the line passing through the origin, and whose direction vector is the cross product between $a$ and $b$.